# How can I use CSS to make a div float over my text whilst remaining in the right spot?

Tags: css, hover, positioning, css-float, css-position

This looks a lot easier than I am probably making it sound.  I have a content div, 600px wide.  It is constantly, for the sake of this argument, in the middle of my page.  It is set in the middle using

`margin: 0px auto;`

In the top right hand corner of this div, I have set a second div, which contains options (it will be share options, such as Facebook, Twitter, etc.).  It is currently controlled using CSS, no Javascript.  When my cursor is away from the Options div, it remains as a button.  When my cursor is over the Options div, it expands.  I want for it to expand over my content, but for my content to still wrap around the original (in this case) 50px square box.

I have two test pages currently uploaded:

[Test 1](http://nathanbunn.kodingen.com/test/divpostest1.html) - This displays the Options div in the correct place (set using `float: right;`), but when I roll over it, the content wraps around the reiszed div.

[Test 2](http://nathanbunn.kodingen.com/test/divpostest2.html) - This makes sure my div floats over my content, but it is set using `position: absolute`, and it remains at the top right hand corner of the page.

I have missed something, I know I have.  Are there any suggestions as to how I can get it working together?  I would prefer solely CSS, but I am not opposed to Javascript, either standalone or using jQuery (I'd prefer that, since other scripts I use in my site use the jQuery framework).  Code is 100% inline for this example, CSS is using  and not  tags, so if you wish to look, it's all there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test 2 would be perfect if you set position: relative; on the containing div and then added a spacer div that remained in the flow of the document: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/GyvM4/

Comment: That has solved my positioning problem, thank you.  However, it hasn't solved my other issue of having my text content wrap around the 50px box that is my button.  Suggestions on that?  The only thing I can think of would be to add a second div with the same dimensions as my button and essentially hide it underneath my options button, but if I can do that without any additional HTML, that would be better.

Comment: I have amended my original comment, works perfectly for me now. You do have to use extra markup though :(

Comment: If I have to use extra markup, I have to use it.  I was just hoping to avoid it where possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Well you could do it using pseudo-elements but then you have cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Check my answer. No extra elements :)

Answer (score 1):

use z-index with absolute postion. Set the z-index to be higher than the content.

Comment: Doing that without setting positioning attributes (`right: 0;` or `top: 0;`) causes the options to sit on the left of the wrapping div.  Once I apply a position attribute, it sits on the right of the _page_, not the wrapping div.  I have tried that in my second test, z-index is set to 1.  It does the same when z-index is set to 10.

Comment: I should also point out that I have tried using `position: relative;`, but also to no avail.  I can upload a test page with this, to show my results.

Comment: Why did this get an upvote? Absolute positioning would automatically raise the z-index sufficiently.

Comment: @joshuanhibbert It got an upvote from me because both his and your answers went someway to helping me.  Figured give credit where it's due, even if it was something I had tried before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7e28/)

It's 1:30am where I am so this is not my best work. Hopefully it should be cross browser compatible.

note I changed #options to options for re-use.

Comment: I shall assume from your time that you too are in the UK ;)  It does work, as desired (only tested in Firefox, shall test others when I wake up).  Doubt I will need to use it on more than one page, but thank you for changing it to a class for me.  I'm sure it would come in handy.

Comment: @Nathan, Yeah I am... It's only ie7 that I'd really be worried about since it has that z-index bug. If I get he chance i'll test it at work today.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7T2c6/ I got it with no extra DOM. However I did move the location of the anchor tag. Outer div no longer provides style, just spacing. Inner elements are position absolute and provide all style. Just my variant. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `position:absolute` without defining a top/right/left/bottom value, and add a `z-index` value. This will keep it in an absolute position but since it's not really specified, it will remain at the required location, causing it to overlap other objects. Play with `margin` to move it around.

Comment: Please refer to the other replies and comments. Also, you want to be using top/left/right/bottom values rather than margin on an absolutely positioned element as it is removed from the flow of the document.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't, because then you wouldn't necessarily be able to know where exactly to put it. If you specify no values for those, the element will stay in it's relative position, but will have `absolute` properties, and you would be able to manipulate it better to fit that need.

Comment: The position is specified: top right corner (first line, second paragraph of question). Also, why would you need to set z-index? Absolute positioning automatically sits it on top of statically positioned elements.